# What is my first name?

Tags: riddle

I met a group of people, but no one told me their names. They just told me these things.

> My name contains myself
>
> My name contains something to put on toast
>
> My name contains a ship able to withstand impossible floods!
>
> My name contains a hiding place for animals
>
> My name contains human creativity
>
> My name contains an indication of
>   point or place
>
> My name contains an acronym where abusers go for help
>
> My name contains the center of the Earth
>
> My name contains the reamins of a fire
>
> My name contains a boobie catcher
>
> My name contains what corn comes on
>
> My name contains a couple thousand pounds
>
> My name contains something that is different from what is expected
>
> My name contains an acronym of an agency created by Franklin D.
>   Roosevelt
>
> My name contains an identifying mark
>
> My name contains another word for steal
>
> My name contains a cars fingerprint

Can you help me identify their first names?

All the names are common names that can be found in America. 
I understand there can be multiple answers for some, I'll take any that fit the clue. (Or multiple if you want to get crazy!)

**HINT**

"My name contains an indication of point or place"

> Think of it from more of a third grade English perspective

"My name contains an identifying mark"

> Think of it from a farmers perspective

Answer (score 4):

My name contains myself

> **Me**l / **Me**lissa

My name contains something to put on toast

> **Jam**es (**Butter**cup is another possibility)

My name contains a ship able to withstand impossible floods!

> Cl**ark** / M**ark** (*Noah's ark was built to withstand impossible floods*)

My name contains a hiding place for animals

> Ai**den** / **Den**ise

My name contains human creativity

> **Art**hur / C**art**er

My name contains an indication of point or place

> Ale**x** / Ma**x** (*X marks the spot*)
>  **There**sa / **There**se

My name contains an acronym where abusers go for help

> Is**aa**c / **Aa**ron (*AA = Alcoholics Anonymous*)

My name contains the center of the Earth

> **Core**y / **Core**en

My name contains the remains of a fire

> **Ash**ley / D**ash**ell

My name contains a boobie catcher

> Bar**bra** / **Bra**dley / **Bra**ndon

My name contains what corn comes on

> Ja**cob** / **Cob**y

My name contains a couple thousand pounds

> Al**ton** / **Ton**y (*A ton is 2,000lbs*)

My name contains something that is different from what is expected

> T**odd**

My name contains an acronym of an agency created by Franklin D. Roosevelt

> **Rea**gan / B**rea**nne (*Roosevelt's "Alphabet Agencies" include REA (Rural Electrification Administration) (now Rural Utilities Service)*)

My name contains an identifying mark

> O**scar** / **Scar**lett (*A scar is an identifying mark*)
>  **Brand**on

My name contains another word for steal

> **Rob**ert / **Rob**in

My name contains a cars fingerprint

> **Vin**cent / Mel**vin**/ Ke**vin**  *(VIN = Vehicle Identification Number)*

Comment: I asked the person and they confirmed their name isn't buttercup, also "Stalker" informed me they all have real names. (See bottom of OP)

Comment: @Timmy I thought you would take any that fit the clue and I feel like buttercup fits

Comment: It sounded more clear in my head than what I typed... I should say any name that fits the answer to the clue I was expecting. With the exception to the agency one, because there are tons of those and that would be cruel. Sorry for the poor wording.

Comment: Very close! You guys almost solved this in the same amount of time it took me to make it! For "My name contains an indication of point or place" think of it from more of a third grade English perspective, and for "My name contains an identifying mark" think of it from a farmers perspective.